# Gradle doesn't make use of an added androidx room-common dependency

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I have added all dependencies for androidx room and the project works.
It however only builds when I have internet access or when the build cache is yet to be cleared.
Below is some part the error it throws when trying to build offline.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:kapt'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1195)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$2100(DefaultConfiguration.java:138)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationTaskDependency.visitDependencies(DefaultConfiguration.java:1661)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmptyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:211)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:66)
        ... 109 more
    Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve androidx.room:room-common:[2.2.3].
```

One look at the log suggests it requires androidx.room:room-common dependency to be added.
I've added and synced the project (with internet access) and it was successful but it still fails at build.

Here's my gradle implementation for room.

```
 implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
 implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$rootProject.roomVersion"
 kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
 implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
 kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
 androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$rootProject.coreTestingVersion"
 implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
 implementation 'androidx.room:room-common:2.2.3'
```

Is there any way to tell Gradle to use the one I've added in my project? Or do I have to always enable my internet because of it?

Comment: _You need internet connection to download dependencies._

Comment: @KaushikBurkule I've already downloaded the dependencies. Gradle just doesn't use the one for room-common.

Comment: Have you added _apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'_   line in gradle file?

Comment: add details of project and module's `build.gradle` files